# Apache logs: do lots of 404s on CONNECT to port 443 indicate a vulnerability?

Tags: apache-2.2, php, django

In my logs I keep getting lots of:

```
"CONNECT XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:443 HTTP/1.0" 404 218 "-" "-"
"CONNECT XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:443 HTTP/1.0" 404 218 "-" "-"
...
"CONNECT XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:443 HTTP/1.0" 404 218 "-" "-"
```

Is this some specific vulnerability?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTTP CONNECT is used for tunnelling. Apache supports this through the use of [mod_proxy_connect](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy_connect.html).

A badly configured proxy with support for CONNECT may be a security vulnerability, so if you don't need it you should disable it.

I'm not sure how Apache responds to a CONNECT request if these aren't enabled, but a 404 seems unlikely; I would rather expect a 405 or 501. As such, you should probably check your configuration.

Comment: +1 This is a more succinct answer than mine. In my test (albeit telnet) example, it indeed reports `400 / Bad Request`. Perhaps the `404` implies it wasn't tunneling but requesting a specific resource?

Answer (score 3):

It's likely an attempt to use your server as a proxy, possibly from a bot-net virus or script-kiddie. Specifically, though, it's (possibly) someone telnetting into your box, like so:

```
$ telnet localhost 80
Trying ::1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
CONNECT google.ca 80

HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
[more header data ... ]
<html ... />
```

Are you running a mail server on that box? Do you, by any chance, have firewall logs indicating repeated connections or connection attempts to port 25?

These two articles detail two troubleshooting cases of this same problem:

- [CONNECT lines in apache access log](http://hintsforums.macworld.com/archive/index.php/t-17462.html)
- [Worrying apache logs](http://forums.vpslink.com/security/8461-connect-lines-apache-access-log.html)

Combined, they offer several fixes (which I'll summarize for posterity, but you should read the whole threads for context):

1. Limit CONNECT in httpd.conf with `<Limit CONNECT>Deny from all</Limit>`
2. Disable `mod_proxy` if you're not using it.

Be on the lookout for lines that **don't** return `404` / `400` (in particular, `200`), because that might indicate they successfully accessed some resource, which *in itself* is not necessarily troubling.